# Give ellipsis in percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to give ellipsis to a `span` element which is inside `td` element. The problem is that the ellipsis is working if and only if I give the `span` element a fixed width i.e width in pixels. But in my project, I can't use a fixed width to the `span` element. The `span` element must be completely stretched inside the respective `td` element which is possible by using `width: 100%`.

*My question is*: How to make the ellipsis work fine by stretching the `span` element completely inside the `td` element?

```
span {
    width: 100%;    /* In pixels, it is working fine */
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/F7pdr/)

I am looking for a solution which can be a pure css or javascript or jQuery. The solution should work in IE8+ and firefox.

PS: I can't calculate the width of the span dynamically due to some project restrictions.

**EDIT**: I can't restrict the widths of the td elements, because I am implementing column resizable on td elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can potentially add a **max-width** property to the **td** element:

```
th, td {
    width: 33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width:200px;
}
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7pdr/1/)

Comment: Man, you are genius. I don't know how this worked. but giving `max-width: 10px` solved the problem. :D. I still need to test it thoroughly though. Thanks.

Comment: Tested. Working fine in IE8+ and firefox. but I am still confused whether to go with this fix or not.

Comment: you could experiment with em instead of px or percentages, then it might be a bit more flexible

Answer (score 4):

In short, you need to add this:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

The cause is not in `span` element but because table's `td` elements do not have defined 33% width - they expand according to width of `td` content. To make them fixed width, you need to apply `table-layout:fixed;` rule to your `table`.

Live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m5gGr/

Comment: I saw this solution before. but I can't do this because I need to do column resize later.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this can help you

```
.parent-div {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;        
    min-width: 0;
}

.icon {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj7By/)**

[More about box-flex property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your solution. :)

Comment: Cool... When u get to know about flex property u will look back here so no issues :)